# .NET WCF Service Client Responds with null value even though there's data in the soap response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have created a WCF Service client that automagically created the Service Reference for me, and sending SOAP request messages works just as expected, but when I receive a SOAP response, I receive data from the envelope, but the Service client comes back as null.  I've looked at several questions that discuss this problem, and it always seems to relate to a NameSpace issue, but the NameSpaces seem to match up.  The names of the attributes also seem to line up.  I have an example of the SOAP message I receive and the service reference that was generated:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:gec="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soapenv:Header />
      <soapenv:Body>
<gec:GECSNIncidentResponse>
  <AssetName>Web</AssetName>
  <RequestId>CAPINC0185961</RequestId>
  <BriefDesc>\DEV_Region\WEB\TEST_JAMS_SONIC</BriefDesc>
  <AssignedGroup>@ELEC INS IT/Operations</AssignedGroup>
  <TranStatus>SUCCESS</TranStatus>
  <RequestURL>https://gecapqa.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sys_id=443fd14b0f0df68070a401cce1050e2c</RequestURL>
  <CreatedBy />
  <Error>
  <ErrorCode />
      <ErrorDetails />
     </Error>
    </gec:GECSNIncidentResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's the Client:

```
   namespace GESonicService.GESonic_Service {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS", ConfigurationName="GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType")]
    public interface GECSNIncidentWSPortType {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS/#Open", ReplyAction="*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1 Open(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest request);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS/#Open", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1> OpenAsync(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest request);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS")]
    public partial class OpenInput : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private OpenInputTranInfo tranInfoField;

        private OpenInputTradPartInfo tradPartInfoField;

        private OpenInputRequestInfo requestInfoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public OpenInputTranInfo TranInfo {
            get {
                return this.tranInfoField;
            }
            set {
                this.tranInfoField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TranInfo");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
        public OpenInputTradPartInfo TradPartInfo {
            get {
                return this.tradPartInfoField;
            }
            set {
                this.tradPartInfoField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TradPartInfo");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
        public OpenInputRequestInfo RequestInfo {
            get {
                return this.requestInfoField;
            }
            set {
                this.requestInfoField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestInfo");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS")]
    public partial class OpenInputTranInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string tranIdField;

        private string interfaceTypeField;

        private string requestTypeField;

        private string tranNameField;

        public OpenInputTranInfo() {
            this.interfaceTypeField = "webservice";
            this.requestTypeField = "incident";
            this.tranNameField = "open";
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public string TranId {
            get {
                return this.tranIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.tranIdField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TranId");
            }
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
        public string InterfaceType {
            get {
                return this.interfaceTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.interfaceTypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("InterfaceType");
            }
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
        public string RequestType {
            get {
                return this.requestTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.requestTypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestType");
            }
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
        public string TranName {
            get {
                return this.tranNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.tranNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TranName");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS")]
    public partial class OpenResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string assetNameField;

        private string requestIdField;

        private string briefDescField;

        private string assignedGroupField;

        private string tranStatusField;

        private string requestURLField;

        private string createdByField;

        private OpenResponseError errorField;

        private string originalDocumentField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public string AssetName {
            get {
                return this.assetNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.assetNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("AssetName");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
        public string RequestId {
            get {
                return this.requestIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.requestIdField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestId");
            }
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
        public string BriefDesc {
            get {
                return this.briefDescField;
            }
            set {
                this.briefDescField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("BriefDesc");
            }
        }[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
        public string AssignedGroup {
            get {
                return this.assignedGroupField;
            }
            set {
                this.assignedGroupField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("AssignedGroup");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
        public string TranStatus {
            get {
                return this.tranStatusField;
            }
            set {
                this.tranStatusField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TranStatus");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
        public string RequestURL {
            get {
                return this.requestURLField;
            }
            set {
                this.requestURLField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestURL");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=6)]
        public string CreatedBy {
            get {
                return this.createdByField;
            }
            set {
                this.createdByField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("CreatedBy");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=7)]
        public OpenResponseError Error {
            get {
                return this.errorField;
            }
            set {
                this.errorField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Error");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=8)]
        public string OriginalDocument {
            get {
                return this.originalDocumentField;
            }
            set {
                this.originalDocumentField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("OriginalDocument");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:GECSNIncidentWS/WSDL/GECSNIncidentWS")]
    public partial class OpenResponseError : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string errorCodeField;

        private string errorDetailsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
        public string ErrorCode {
            get {
                return this.errorCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.errorCodeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorCode");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
        public string ErrorDetails {
            get {
                return this.errorDetailsField;
            }
            set {
                this.errorDetailsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorDetails");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class OpenResponse1 {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
        public GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse GECSNIncidentResponse;

        public OpenResponse1() {
        }

        public OpenResponse1(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse GECSNIncidentResponse) {
            this.GECSNIncidentResponse = GECSNIncidentResponse;
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeChannel : GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType>, GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType {

        public GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient() {
        }

        public GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public GECSNIncidentWSPortTypeClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }        
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1 GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType.Open(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.Open(request);
        }

        public GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse Open(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenInput Open1) {
            GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest inValue = new GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest();
            inValue.Open = Open1;
            GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1 retVal = ((GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType)(this)).Open(inValue);
            return retVal.GECSNIncidentResponse;
        }        
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1> GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType.OpenAsync(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.OpenAsync(request);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenResponse1> OpenAsync(GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenInput Open) {
            GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest inValue = new GESonicService.GESonic_Service.OpenRequest();
            inValue.Open = Open;
            return ((GESonicService.GESonic_Service.GECSNIncidentWSPortType)(this)).OpenAsync(inValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a lot of information, but any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try re-generating your client proxy code? Some time ago I had a similar problem (my trace file confirmed there was data traveling down the wire, but it ended up as NULL in my client code). The problem was that the service contract had been edited in the meantime and my client proxy code wasn't completly compatible anymore. I recreated it using svcutil.exe/Service Reference dialog and it worked like a charme again.

Comment: In your contract you should remove the ReplyAction="*" on the server side and the try to regenerate your client.

Comment: @RomEh - This isn't my server side code and I don't have access to it.